# login with ajax that changes with web inspector

Tags: php, ajax, web-inspector

I'm studying ajax and I have a doubt about safety.
I have this php function that checks the status of the sessions.

```
public function index()
{
        $logged = is_logged_APP();
        if(!$logged)
        {
            echo "0";
        }   
}
```

Here I have an ajax call that gets the session status.

```
$.post(base_URL+"/MainAPP",function(data)
    {
        if(data == 0)
        {
            alert('not logged in');
        }
        else
        {
            alert('logged in');
        }

    }).fail(function() 
    {
        alert( "error" );
    });
```

If I change the status of the 'if condition' and save the js file I get 'logged in' ... I'm missing something?
Thanks

Comment: AJAX or not you should check login status server side as well in every case

Comment: I check it on every page in the constructor. The problem is the condition in the js file

Answer (score 0):

You should use sessions with php to only deliver content for a logged in session.

To address your concern, it would be equivalent to setting the alert to "logged in" by adding the code:

```
alert("logged in..");
```

You can do it just by telling your browser to do it with no trick to your conditional or called function, but what's the point beyond mimicking the login page unless your client side data already has data it shouldn't have?

Basically, your php is the gate  keeper to your client. Anything within javascript should be considered public knowledge after it's sent to the client.

Edit: You have a few options to redirect a page, but the point is to verify the user's authentication once you get to the restricted content, so you're going to have to verify that it is them when you get to that page. You can use the php header function:

```
header("Location: auth.php");
```

Notice that I point to a php file? You'll want to use something like cookies or session variables that are unique and non-reoccurring per user to verify that it is them once they get to that page. Then you can display the relevant information based on which user it is. Dumping an html file in your public folder and then checking passwords just to redirect to that page is pointless. You can even use javascript to redirect the page with:

```
window.location = "auth.php";
```

But the issue will remain that you have to verify them in php, so there really isn't a point (or even a positive security aspect) to including ajax in the login/authentication process other than if you want php to provide values back to edit the current page.

Comment: This is clear to me, but if I have to redirect to the user page how can I do without going through an if? if(logged in) href to private page; grazie

Comment: Or use get_file_contents. The point is to place the information out of the users (or anyone else's) reach. It won't help if they can browse to the page, so you might want to send the information with an ajax request to a page that checks session variables.

Comment: Summing up what I said, basically php is the only thing that cares about security, so you have to provide things to your user through php, not just using ajax. Instead of returning 0, return the protected information. That is what ajax is used for.

Comment: I understood, grazie